# Can't get my column vertically aligned in row

Tags: vertical-alignment

I would want to vertically align that col-md-3 div in the row. I tried the majority of the solutions found on stackoverflow. Can you help me ? I have this code:

```css
.content-wrap-optin{
 background-color: #1ED037;
 padding: 0 0;
 height: 220px;
}


.optin-text-row{
 display: table;
}

.optin-text-col{
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap content-wrap-optin">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="row clearfix optin-text-row"> 

            <!-- Call to action -->
            <div class="col-md-3 optin-text-col">
                <p class="optin-text">Descarca Gratuit 7 carti marca Zig Zag prin Romania si descopera valorile autentice romanesti!</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container clearfix -->
</div><!-- content-wrap -->
```

Comment: I fixed the problem with this: `.optin-text-row{
 position: relative;
    height: 220px;
}

.optin-text-col{
 top: 53%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}`